# How do I set an equal box-shadow for all 4 sides?

Tags: css

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/any_formless/pen/RwKgGOm

My box shadow is different on the sides than on the top, and the bottom is totally missing.

```css
.example {
  
  border-radius: 3vw;
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px -10px rgb(0 0 0), inset -10px 10px 10px -10px rgb(0 0 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applicable syntax for the `box-shadow` property is:

```
/* inset | offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
```

This is not to be confused with the shorthand syntax for certain box-model properties (e.g. `margin` or `padding`) which is:

```
/* top | right | bottom | left */
```

To achieve an evenly placed border, `offset-x` and `offset-y` should be `0`:

```css
.example {
  border-radius: 3vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px rgb(0 0 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Text</div>
```

Multiple independent shadows can be created using commas.

The original example is essentially creating two overlapping shadows, one for the top/left and one for the top/right:

```css
.example { 
  border-radius: 3vw;
  box-shadow:
    inset 6px 5px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0),  /* left and top */
    inset -6px 5px 5px 0 rgb(0 0 0)  /* right and top */
  ;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Text</div>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Comment: And what is the correct code, if I want to keep the current code, but I want to remove the bottom? In the initial code there are 2 statements divided with a comma, so I am not sure that that is correct. Why are 2 statements there? I can use this code (your example) but I need a version which is the same, but with the bottom shadow completely removed. How do I offset it to both left and right, and to the top but not to the bottom?

Comment: The original example is the correct way to achieve a pseudo '3-sided' shadow. I've added an explanation to the answer. Try removing either the `left and top` or `right and top` lines to better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Hello use something like this:

```
.example {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) inset;
}
```

Also, don't forget to make the last **px** before **rgba** the same number for all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 4 values before `color` for box-shadow, respectively they mean:

```
offset-x, offset-y, blur-radius, spread-radius
```

For your example, if you would like to have all sides equal, you should not give any value to `offset-x` and `offset-y`.

So, something like that:

```css
.example {
  
  border-radius: 3vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px -10px rgb(0 0 0), inset 0 0 10px -10px rgb(0 0 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">Text</div>
```